# When does data-dash-is-loading trigger a callback function?

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, plotly.js, plotly-python

I am trying to show a spinner when a Dash figure is updated using the CSS attribute `data-dash-is-loading`.

I found a working solution but would like to know why my previous approach does not work to get more insight.

The structure of the document is

```
html.Div(id="some-container",
         children=[dcc.Graph(id="some-graph",
                             figure=fig)])
```

These are the two callback functions I tried, one at a time.
The working callback function updates the children of the whole container:

```
@app.callback(
Output("some-container", "children"),
[Input("some-dropdown", "value")])
```

The callback function that does not work is

```
@app.callback(
Output("some-graph", "figure"),
[Input("some-dropdown", "value")])
```

Well, it works fine, it updates the figure as is should, but it does not trigger the `data-dash-is-loading`.

The CSS code is taken from [here](https://dash.plot.ly/loading-states):

```
*[data-dash-is-loading="true"]{
    visibility: hidden;
}
*[data-dash-is-loading="true"]::before{
    content: "Loading...";
    display: inline-block;
    color: magenta;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Can someone tell me what the reason is?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you're overwriting the children of your div `some-container`. When the second callback is fired, it's possible that the graph `"some-graph"` doesn't exist any longer.

A workaround for this would be to create 2 separate divs for your graph and updated items.

Comment: I only use one callback function at a time, I exchanged them. The graph still exists, since I can see it, right? Updating the figure works fine, it just does not trigger data-dash-is-loading.

Comment: Do yo have an idea?